# Изменение значения в структуре через указатель

Tags: visual-c++

Не получается изменить значение переменной в структуре через указатель. В чём ошибка?

```
struct ko
    {
        int i;
        double n;
        char r[3];
    };
ko* a;
    a->r = "ab";
```

Answer (score 0):

запись `a->r = "ab"` в С++ означает, что переменной `a->r` присваивается указатель на константную строку `"ab"`, а не копируется эта строка в массив. Соответственно, есть два варианта. Первый - объявить поле `r`, как указатель на `const char`:

```
struct ko
    {
        int i;
        double n;
        const char* r; //указатель
    };
ko* a;
    a->r = "ab";
```

Второй - вместо присваивания использовать `strcpy()` или ещё лучше `strncpy()`:

```
struct ko
    {
        int i;
        double n;
        char r[3]; //массив
    };
ko* a;
    strncpy(a->r, "ab", 2);
    a->r[2] = '\0'; //обязательно завершить нулём!
```

Comment: И, добавлю свои 5 копеек для ТС - надеюсь, вы понимаете, что указатель `a` должен быть инициализирован и указывать на существующкю, доступную память объекта типа `ko`?

Comment: @Harry кстати да. Вчера ночью уже плохо соображал, по-этому не обратил внимания